# Export data to csv with different data types per column

Tags: r, excel, csv, data.table

I need to provide colleagues with a csv, which they can easily use in Excel. The different parts of the csv are stored in different data.tables, because they differ in their structure.
The problem now arises, that whenever I would like to export the data.tables into one csv the data type of columns with numerical and string values is set to `chr` and this of course creates issues in Excel with the numbers. (Please also mind that the issue is much worse, since it's Germany and we are using a different decimal separator.) I think this is caused by the fact that most of the export tools `fwrite`, `write.csv`, first `rbind` the data.tables into one and export it then.
Is there a way to create a csv, which can store different data.types in one column? Currently I store each data.table per csv file, but thus I am creating manual work, which I would rather not.

A small minimal working example:

```
library(data.table)

dt.a <- data.table(D = letters[12:22]
                      , E = seq(from = 10, to = 11, by = 0.1)
                      )


dt.b <- data.table(A = seq(from = 1, to =2, by = 0.1)
                        , B = letters[1:11]
                        )

fwrite(x = rbind(dt.b
       , dt.a
       , use.names = FALSE)
       , file = "test.csv"
       , sep = ";"
       , dec = ","
       , col.names = FALSE 
       , row.names = FALSE
)
```

This results in a csv-file like the following and as can be seen the format of the numbers is not easily importable in Excel.

```
1;a
1.1;b
1.2;c
1.3;d
1.4;e
1.5;f
1.6;g
1.7;h
1.8;i
1.9;j
2;k
l;10
m;10.1
n;10.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is no:

> Is there a way to create a csv, which can store different data.types in one column?

Columns are vectors consisting of exactly one type/class. You can create list columns, i.e. columns that are lists and can thus contain heterogeneous elements, but I don't think that would translate well to an Excel table.

Your options are:

1. Create multiple CSVs for each data.table,
2. bind your data.tables by column using `cbind(dt.a, dt.b)` instead of by row,
3. or just export multiple sheets directly to XLSX using the `writexl` library. This is probably your best option. Try something like this:

```r
writexl::write_xlsx(list(dt_a = dt.a, dt_b = dt.b), "test.xlsx")
```

The output is an XLSX with two sheets corresponding to your two data.tables.

I should probably mention that the `writexl` developers have included a (mal)functioning Clippy in the documentation. I personally think it's kind of funny, but many people are [very annoyed](https://github.com/ropensci/writexl/issues/12).

[image]

Comment: Apparently, there's quite a lack of humour...  :-) I mean reporting it to CRAN is really petty. :-)